Accessing path params of FormRequest
I have this code:
class BunnyUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => ['required', 'min:1'],
            'status' => ['required', Rule::enum(BunnyStatus::class)]
        ];
    }

    public function validationData(){
        return array_merge($this->all(), [
            'id' => $this->route()->parameter('bunny_id'),
            'status' => $this->route()->parameter('status')
        ]);
    }
}

class BunnyController extends Controller
{
    public function update(BunnyUpdateRequest $bunnyUpdateRequest)
    {
        $fields = $bunnyUpdateRequest->validated();
        $bunny = Bunny::findOrFail($fields['id']);
        if ($bunny->status === BunnyStatus::Done)
            return Response::json(null, 422);
        $bunny->status = $fields['status'];
        $bunny->save();
        return Response::json(null, 200);
    }
}

Normally I would use $request->input to get the validated body input field or query param. As far as I understand validation runs in this case. At least I hope so. The upper code gets path params which are empty if I try to get the same way. This is why I used the validated() array. I don't like this approach, because I find the code ugly. Is there a way to get these path params as object properties on the request object just as body input fields and query params? Is there a way to get a Bunny instance instead of the id with request model binding somehow?

Have you tried this $fields->status?In case it is not working what error you are getting?

@Subha As far as I remember it gives null. But I can try it now.

Okay let me know about what did you get.And also inform whether the code is working as expected if you use the core array format syntax.

@Subha It gave null, but I figured out that I have to use a different method to merge the parameters with other input data. See my answer below. I checked, validation runs on it too, so I no longer have to call the validated method.

1st of all the answer you provided is good one, from the conventional point of view i.e. you fetched the two parameters from the URL then validated (using custom Form Request) and updated the records if  BunnyStatus not equal to DONE.
But Laravel itself provides some in built features with which you can do the same operation with lesser lines of code as well as without custom Form Request.
That is the reason I am writing this answer which will provide another perspective to do the same and also help you to manage 404 error automatically.
Change Your Route defination like this.
use App\Http\Controllers\BunnyController;
use App\Models\Bunny;
use App\Enums\BunnyStatus;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

Route::post('bunnies/{bunny}/update-status/{status}', [BunnyController::class, 'update'])
    ->missing(function (Request $request) {
        // Redirect to custom error page or wherever you want your user to redirect if if an implicitly bound `model/Enum` is not found.
        return Redirect::route('404'); 
    });

Above I have implemented implicit model binding , implicit enum binding along with missing model/enum Behaviour.That is the reason you will not need custom form request because basic-validation will be done there.
Then in the Controller do this. This will by default fetch & injected to the update() method the matching model instance of the Bunny model as Bunny $bunny & BunnyStatus $status as Enum passed to the URL after validation that is being done in the Route defination.
    public function update(Bunny $bunny, BunnyStatus $status): 
    {
        // Check if the status is 'DONE' and return a 422 response
        if ($status === BunnyStatus::DONE) {
            return Response::json(null, 422);
        }

        // Update the Bunny's status
        $bunny->status = $status->value;
        $bunny->save();

        
        return Response::json(null, 200);
    }

Remember to import these class and also the orther required class to the top of the Controller class.
use App\Models\Bunny;
use App\Enums\BunnyStatus;

Citation:-

Implicit Model Binding
Implicit Enum Binding
Customizing Missing Model/Enum Behavior


Having request and JSON resource/collection classes is a convention in our team. I just wanted to use them the most optimal way possible. Though using the path params in the form request was my idea. Maybe it is not the way Laravel should be used.

I have a solution:
class BunnyUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'bunny' => ['required'],
            'status' => ['required', Rule::enum(BunnyStatus::class)]
        ];
    }

    protected function prepareForValidation(): void {
        $this->merge([
            'bunny' => Bunny::findOrFail($this->route()->parameter('bunny_id')),
            'status' => $this->route()->parameter('status')
        ]);
    }
}

class BunnyController extends Controller
{
    public function update(BunnyUpdateRequest $request)
    {
        $bunny = $request->bunny;
        if ($bunny->status === BunnyStatus::Done)
            return Response::json(null, 422);
        $bunny->status = $request->status;
        $bunny->save();
        return Response::json(null, 200);
    }
}

Instead of using the validationData method I use the prepareForValidation to merge the path params. I movee the findOrFail to the request. It gives 404 for a non existent bunny this way too.

It is a good answer, upvoted. But i think that you are not using implicit model binding in your route defination. If you would have used it then it can be easier to handle the 404 error for non existent bunny_id.Can you please share your route defination so that it is understood that whether this answer will be improved in terms of handling 404 error automatically?

@Subha It is Route::post('bunnies/{bunny_id}/update-status/{status}', [BunnyController::class, 'update']);. It gives the 404 error with this code, but you can edit the answer if you know something better. (Note that I would have done PUT bunnies/{bunny}/status if it would be my code.) Not sure how to do request model binding with FormRequest.

Hi I have posted my answer without editing yours. Please go through it and let me know your feedback.Thanks.
